# How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+\sin^2 n}{n+n^{1.5}}$?

Tags: calculus

How can I evaluate this sum? My teacher asked but I can't get it.

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+\sin^2 n}{n+n^{1.5}}$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you need to *evaluate* it or do you need to find out whether it converges or not?

Comment: nothing because i felt there is no answer

Comment: i need to evaluate it or  to find out whether it converges or not
every thing lead me to any thing

Comment: do you know the comparison test?

Comment: not sure if i know it

Comment: another  question 
how to find the sum of k^-p from k=1 to m

Comment: You'll have more luck with your other question if you ask it as a new question ;)
Before you do though, see if anyone else has asked that question before: it seems like one you might find elsewhere on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot expect a nice closed form answer to this. However, it is easy to show that it is bounded and thereby it converges. We have $\sin^2(n) \in (0,1)$. Hence, $1+\sin^2(n) \in (1,2)$.

We also have $n+n^{1.5} \in (n^{1.5}, 2n^{1.5})$. Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{1+\sin^2(n)}{n+n^{1.5}} \in \left(\dfrac1{2n^{1.5}}, \dfrac2{n^{1.5}} \right)$$
We hence have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1+\sin^2(n)}{n+n^{1.5}} \in \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{2n^{1.5}}, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac2{n^{1.5}} \right) = \left(\dfrac{\zeta(3/2)}2, 2 \zeta(3/2)\right)$$

Comment: @mohammad.mnsh If you have a new question, you need to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you series is a positive one and

$$\frac{1+\sin^2n}{n+n^{1.5}}\le\frac2{n^{3/2}}$$

Thus your series converges.